Should I rescale images again in ImageDataGenerator after normalizing grayscale images?
I am working on an image classification task using a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN). During preprocessing, I convert RGB images to grayscale and normalize them by dividing the pixel values by 255. After this normalization step, I use ImageDataGenerator for data augmentation. However, I am uncertain if I need to include the rescale parameter in ImageDataGenerator during data augmentation or if I should remove it because the images are already normalized.

You must rescale just once. Because you did it beforehand, including the recale parameter in ImageDataGenerator will rescale the recaled images and things go wrong.
